# R Shiny: How to make the initial value for numericInput dynamic, based on user input

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, responsive

I'm trying to make the `value` argument for `shiny::numericInput()` dynamic, based on input from a user.

Both code chunks below will run, but they fail to set a dynamic initial value.

**Chunk 1:**

```
idOptions <- c("1","2","3")

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::selectInput(inputId = "idSelection", "Identification: ", idOptions),
  shiny::numericInput("num", "Number associated with id:", value=shiny::verbatimTextOutput("numberOut")),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"), number = c(100,227,7))
  output$numberOut <- shiny::renderText({ input$idSelection })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Chunk 2:**

```
idOptions <- c("1","2","3")

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::selectInput(inputId = "idSelection", "Identification: ", idOptions),
  shiny::numericInput("num", "Number associated with id:", value=shiny::verbatimTextOutput("numberOut")),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"), number = c(100,227,7))
  dfReactive <- shiny::reactive({
    dataOut <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(., id %in% input$idSelection)
    return(dataOut)
  })
  shiny::observe({
    output$numberOut <- shiny::renderText({ 
      return(dfReactive()$number)
    })
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want the initial value for `shiny::numericInput` to change like so:

When the user selects "1" for Identification, the initial value is 100:

[image]

When the user selects "2" for Identification, the initial value is 227:

[image]

The idea behind this is to have an appropriate initial value suggested to the user based on the identification of the input.

I'm guessing the problem might be with `shiny::verbatimTextOutput("numberOut")`, but I don't know a way to render a simple numeric value to pass into the `value` argument of `shiny::numericInput`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `renderUI` and do the computation on the server side:

```
idOptions <- c("1","2","3")

shiny::shinyApp(

  ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::selectInput(inputId = "idSelection", "Identification: ", idOptions),
    shiny::uiOutput("num")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    df <- data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"), number = c(100,227,7))
    
    output$num <- shiny::renderUI({
      shiny::numericInput("num",
                          "Number associated with id:",
                          value = df$number[as.numeric(input$idSelection)])
    })
    
})
```

The alternative is to leave the input on the UI side and use `updateNumericInput` inside an `observeEvent`:

```
idOptions <- c("1","2","3")

shiny::shinyApp(
  
  ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    
    shiny::selectInput(inputId = "idSelection",
                       "Identification: ",
                       idOptions),
    
    shiny::numericInput("num",
                        "Number associated with id:",
                        value = NULL)
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    df <- data.frame(id = c("1","2","3"),
                     number = c(100,227,7))
    
    observeEvent(input$idSelection, {
      updateNumericInput(session,
                         inputId = "num",
                         value = df$number[as.numeric(input$idSelection)])
    })
  })
```

Comment: @awag1: I also updated a second way to do it. See what works best for you. As a general rule to avoid bugs and errors it is good to avoid using outputs as arguments in UI functions.

Comment: I've validated that both your suggestions work on my end; I'll be deciding which to employ in my actual app shortly. Thanks again for the quick work!